# How can I iterate on a Jekyll /Liquid collection items by batch of 3?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a base HTML structure where I display 3 items per row. In order to properly separate them, I use 2 borders (first/second second/third) like in the following schema:

```
ITEM1 | ITEM2 | ITEM3
```

defined using SASS as follows:

```
         .middle {
                position: relative;
                z-index: 1;

                &:before {
                    content: '';
                    width: 32px;
                    height: 100%;
                    position: absolute;
                    left: -24px;
                    top: 0;
                    display: block;
                    z-index: -1;
                    box-shadow: 32px 0 0 0 #fff, 0 -32px 0 0 #fff, 0 32px 0 0 #fff, 32px 32px 0 0 #fff, 32px -32px 0 0 #fff, 0 0 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
                }

                &:after {
                    content: '';
                    width: 32px;
                    height: 100%;
                    position: absolute;
                    right: -24px;
                    top: 0;
                    display: block;
                    z-index: -1;
                    box-shadow: -32px 0 0 0 #fff, 0 -32px 0 0 #fff, 0 32px 0 0 #fff, -32px 32px 0 0 #fff, -32px -32px 0 0 #fff, 0 0 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
                }
            }
```

I would like to distinguish between these 3 row items when I iterate on a Jekyll collection. To rephrase, iterate on items 3 by 3.
 it
I just started looking into Jekyll a couple hours ago and I could see that [filters are available](https://gist.github.com/smutnyleszek/9803727), but I have no idea of how to achieve this in a standard collection iteration like the following:

```
{% for item in array %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

https://gist.github.com/smutnyleszek/9803727

Comment: Seems like you could achieve this using CSS3 [:nth-child](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/) selector, which allows you to select one or more elements based on their source order. This way you would not need to add a class to the 'middle' item.

Comment: Thank you @ShannonYoung . I will rely on Liquid to make it more lightweight but I will definitely use that trick in other projects or situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to group items in a row while iterating we use the `modulo` filter:

> Divides an output by a number and returns the remainder.

Then we can identify each iteration and more specifically, which of the three items we are processing by doing `forloop.index | modulo: 3`:

If the remainder is 1, is the first item in the row, if is 2 then it is the second one, if it is 0 it would be the third one. for example iterating through the array `site.posts`

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
{% assign mod = forloop.index | modulo: 3 %}
{{ mod }}:{{post.title}}
{% if mod == 1 %}
<div>first item</div>
{% elsif mod == 2 %}
<div class="middle">second item</div>
{% else %}
<div>third item</div>
<hr>
{% endif %}
<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Note that based on your code I've applied the `middle` css class to the second item.

This would output:

```
 1:First post title
first item

2:Second post title
second item

0:Third post title
third item

-----------------

1:Fourth post title
first item
```

Comment: I was just about to try with modulo. Nice. Do you think it is better to handle this using css as suggested in the question comment, or should I stick to the filters? I assume the latter since it is preprocessed, so it should be easier for the client browser.

Comment: Since you seem to have your way with Liquid, I would like to ask your opinion if you don't mind. This is a quite old technology. Do you think it is still a good choice to learn and use it nowadays or is there a more recent/elegant alternative for static websites?

Comment: I would prefer using filters, it gives me more flexibility but both choices are valid.

Comment: Learning Liquid is a good choice as it is the default templating system in Jekyll, you will also be able to understand other popular templating systems like Jinja and Twig, as they are very similar.

Comment: Thank you for sharing :)